# my tourist visa application was refused at french embassy in nigeria

Tags: visa-refusals, schengen-visas, nigerian-citizens

The only reason i was refused visa at France embassy was " the justification of the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided" this happened twice in a year for the same reasons. what can i do to overturn this decision and can i legally apply to other EU states like Spain?

Comment: Hi Alaba. There is already another question at this page that has a good answer that also answers your question.

Comment: @Alaba Enilolobo A refusal from one Schengen country does not prevent you from legally applying to another. However, you are highly likely to get another refusal unless you can submit a stronger application and/or your personal circumstances improve before you apply again. Read the duplicate question and if you have a specific problem which the duplicate doesn’t answer, please edit your question to provide sufficient information to get a specific answer.

Comment: You should also consider that many people from Nigeria apply and many with false documents and/or false intention (and many will not return to home country). For this reason the applications from some countries are extra checked and you must provide stronger proofs. It is not your fault, but this is the world, and nobody as the right to obtain a visa.